# Mongoose. Query for documents for which specific value within an object array does not exist

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Model:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    userLog: [
        {
            name: String,
            logflag: Boolean,
            logTime: Date
        }
    ],
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Sample Documents:

```
{
    "name" : User_1,
    "userLog" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("598ac4ac4cd6945012e3eac9"),   
            "name" : "Start",
            "logflag" : true,
            "logTime" : "06:00"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("598ac4ac4cd6945012e3eaca"),
            "name" : "Mid Day",     
            "logTime" : "12:00",
            "logflag" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("598ac4ac4cd6945012e3eacb"),
            "name" : "End",
            "logflag" : false,      
            "logTime" : "18:00"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : User_2,
    "userLog" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5989c1ec498267d015ca33c9"),
            "name" : "Start",
            "logflag" : true,       
            "logTime" : "18:00"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5989c1ec498267d015ca33ca"),
            "name" : "End", 
            "logflag" : true,       
            "logTime" : "06:00"
        }   
    ]
}
```

I am looking for a query that retrieves Users that have **ALL** 'logflags' set to true (or **NO** logflag set to false). The array has variable number of objects.

In the above example, the query would return User_2.

I have tried the following:

```
User.find({ "userLog.logflag": {$ne: false}})
```

which does not work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you say it does not work? Because it actually does. This is basically a "multikey" property in that by the referenced path if "any element" matches the condition then it is true. Since the first document contains elements that actually have a `false` value then the condition is `false` and that document does not return. Only the second document can be returned because none of the elements have the `false` value. You don't need `$elemMatch` when there is only one property inside the array to test. And you don't need `$not` to negate an assertion that is already negative.

Comment: @NeilLunn, you are quite right, it does work. My mistake. What does not work for me is using the same query with User.update

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your query

```
User.find({ "userLog": {$elemMatch: { logflag: true}}})
```

Comment: The above query isn't the desired one. Because it will pull users who may even have array elements "logflag: false" along with "logflag: true".  The expected result in original question is "User_2" but this will give both "User_1" and "User_2".

Comment: your observation is quite right @dilsingi.